# Behringer Eurolive B115D for keyboards

Tags: speakers, live, keyboard, loudspeakers

I was thinking of purchasing a speaker for my keyboard. I was looking at the Behringer Eurolive B115D [1]. Based on the specs, would I be able to connect my keyboard directly to the speaker OR would I have to purchase a mixer also? Thanks for your help!!

[1]https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/B115D

Comment: Would you mind specifying why you need this? Do you need it just for amplification (e.g. for practice) or is it for monitoring? It would also help answer this if we knew what the keyboard is and what kind of outputs it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from the question whether the keyboard has a mono or stereo output so it's hard to say if you would need one or two of these. They do have 2 inputs but it will just mix them together. For true stereo you would need two and you would need them placed so that they form an equilateral triangle with the listener (you).

It is also unclear whether the keyboard gives out one, two or more outputs and  what kind of connector is used. I assume that you have 2x 1/4" jacks which is the most common. If so, one of them, the left, is usually marked as the mono output and you could connect it directly to the speaker's input. If you decide to connect both outputs, you might get cancellations with wide stereophonic sounds (ones where the phase between the left and right channel varies greatly). Otherwise you should use two of them.

Finally, these are PA speakers. They are not for monitoring in a studio setting. This means they are designed to be loud, not flat. If that's what you're after, they are absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! This speaker would just be for amplification (churches, banquet halls, etc). I have a budget of $200 - $300. A keyboard amplifier in this price range does not seem sufficient (in regards to volume). The keyboard does have 2 x 1/4" jacks, one of which is marked "mono output". At the moment, I don't need true stereo.